# Javascript add missing days time series results

Tags: javascript, date, underscore.js, time-series

I have an object of results from an aggregate operation against Mongodb, the result is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "avg": 3,
        "min": 3,
        "max": 3,
        "total": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "avg": 1,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1,
        "total": 12
    }
]
```

I need to add the missing dates with zero values, so for example if I asked for a range of a week starting from 20 January I'd like to have a result object like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "avg": 3,
        "min": 3,
        "max": 3,
        "total": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-01-21T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "avg": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "max": 0,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-01-22T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "avg": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "max": 0,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "hit",
            "date": "2015-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "avg": 1,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 1,
        "total": 12
    },
    {...}
]
```

The array with dates range is this:

```
[ 
"2015-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
"2015-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
"2015-01-22T00:00:00.000Z",
"2015-01-23T00:00:00.000Z",
"2015-01-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"2015-01-25T00:00:00.000Z",
"2015-01-26T00:00:00.000Z",
]
```

For each date in this array I have to add a zero value object into the previous results.

I tried something with underscore and map/reduce/clone but I cannot get the right results.

Any help please?

Comment: where are you having an issue?

Comment: I cannot understand how to do it with underscore, I have an array with all the dates that should be in the result but I cannot intersect it with the mongodb results.

Comment: can you just post that array as well.

Comment: Posted, please look, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it, but I miss to add zero values, I'm going to do that now.

```
        var cloneItem = {};

        // Generate the date range arrays with single days
        var range = moment().range(new Date(req.query.datefrom), new Date(req.query.dateto)),
            days = [];
        range.by('days', function(moment) {
            days.push(moment.startOf('day').format());
        });

        // Rewrite dates to match the same date range format from the array above
        webstat = _.map(webstat, function (value, key, list) {
            value._id.date = moment(value._id.date).startOf('day').format();
            if (key === 0) cloneItem = value;
            return value;
        });

        // Add the object values when they are missed               
        days.forEach(function (day) {
            var clone = _.extend({}, cloneItem, {_id: {action: cloneItem._id.action, date: day}});

            if (_.findWhere(webstat, {_id: { date: day}}) === undefined) {
                webstat.push(clone);
            }
        });

        // Sort by date and send it
        res.jsonp(
            _.sortBy(webstat, function (item) {
                return item._id.date;
            })
        );
```